# Add a UIRefreshControl below a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

Is there any way to add a UIRefreshControl below a UITableView? I created a [preview](http://postimg.org/image/6q70x2gyr/) of what I want to achieve.

Comment: There is already a good post available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942460/uirefreshcontrol-at-the-bottom-of-the-uitableview-ios6

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These won't give the UIRefresh Controls but you can add these at the bottom of the Screen

Declare below in your header

```
  UIActivityIndicatorView                             *spinner;
```

Initialise  the same in ViewDidLoad in your implementation

```
spinner = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    self.tableviewName.tableFooterView = spinner;
```

Add These and it will be called when tableview Scrolled

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    float reload_distance = 50;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        NSLog(@"load more data");
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
}
```

Hope This will help you out !

Comment: good solution! I'm using this, with a little modifies:     [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES; And I detect if I'm at the really end of the table view, and there [spinner stopAnimating];

Comment: solution is good but i have one query after hiding activity indicator table is not scrolled down . Please let me know if you have any solution for this too .