# UITableView's subview not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, subview

I have a UITableViewController subclass. When I try to add a subView its not showing.

The subView is a UIImageView, I made a custom loading view (its shown when user is loading data from web).

But when I add,

```
[self.tableView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

The spinner is not showing. What am I missing or I did wrong?

**EDIT**

Code of spinner

```
UIImageView *spinner = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
spinner.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin8.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin7.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin6.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin5.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin4.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin3.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin2.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin1.png"],
                          nil];
```

Comment: please put code of **spiner**

Comment: Try implementing this in your code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837787/add-a-uirefreshcontrol-below-a-uitableview/20838552#20838552

Comment: set `frame` to `spinner`

Comment: Set frame for the `UIImageView`

Comment: I don't think thats the problem. Because I used same code in other subclasses UIViewController. Its not showing in the subclasses of UITableViewController. Can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: @Rashad - try with [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront: spiner];

Comment: @ipatel I tried but not helping.. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CGRect spinnerFrame = //frame of spinner
UIImageView *spinner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:spinnerFrame];
spinner.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin8.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin7.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin6.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin5.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin4.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin3.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"spin1.png"],
                      nil];

[self.tableView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Comment: >> Your solution worked but can you tell the reason why it didn't work in tableView subclass? It is working fine in viewController subclass.

Comment: in viewController subclass, you used `initWithImage:` or `init`.? Because setting the image property does not change the size of a UIImageView, but `initWithImage:` does see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_9). And are you sure not setting any frame to `UIImageView` in viewController subclass.?

Comment: Yes I am sure. In my viewController i used "spinner = [[UIImageView alloc]init];"

Answer (score 1):

Use [MBProgress HUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)
Its an custom control through which you can easily add various type of Loading indicator

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithProgressCallback:^(float progress) {
hud.progress = progress;
} completionCallback:^{
[hud hide:YES];
}];
```

Use above code or there are lot of other options as well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the tableView's contentView:

```
[self.tableVew.contentView addSubview:spinner];
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake -- I was thinking of the tableview's cell. Sorry!

Comment: i am not trying to add sub to tableViewCell I am trying to add subView to tableView while loading data from web.