# how to show pull up to refresh control in the bottom of tableview?

Tags: ios

In the tableView , when I am pulling down from the top, it is fetching the data. But if I want pulling up the data from the bottom in tableView, how can I implement, please suggest me

Comment: https://github.com/151283250/MJRefresh

Answer (score 15):

I too stucked with such a situation and at last i found some answers like [UIRefreshControl at the bottom of the UITableView iOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942460/uirefreshcontrol-at-the-bottom-of-the-uitableview-ios6) and thus implemeted our `UIActivityIndicatorView` in footerview. Thus it is working fine Now.

```
    // call this method in `viewDidLoad` and connect the tableview delegates.

    -(void)initializeRefreshControl
    {
        indicatorFooter = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableVeiwMarkets.frame), 44)];
        [indicatorFooter setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [indicatorFooter startAnimating];
        [self.tableVeiwMarkets setTableFooterView:indicatorFooter];
    }

    -(void)refreshTableVeiwList
    {
// your refresh code goes here
    }
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
    {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height == scrollView.contentSize.height)
        {
            [self refreshTableVeiwList];
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i want to set text with indicatorFooter , how can i set the text|?

Comment: You can add the label to that footer view. Thus you can create a custom indicator view.

Comment: Genius solution. How did i never thought of that? Hahaha.

Answer (score 4):

Please find the below control for show the pull to refresh at bottom of tableview

URL : https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl

Comment: This only refreshes one time. its not calling refresh function for 2nd time pull refresh.

Comment: Ok I found answer by myself... we need to call [refreshcontroll endRefreshing]; after finishing loading

Comment: CCBottomPullToRefresh orks in my Swift project, but the activity indicator does not show. Can u help

Comment: Thanks @RamkrishnaSharma for help

Comment: My tab bar height was an issue, so indicator was hides behind it. Works fine now thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've made this **Swift** library to add pull to refresh to the bottom of `UITableview`.

https://github.com/marwendoukh/PullUpToRefresh-iOS

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MNMBottomPullToRefresh](https://github.com/emenegro/bottom-pull-to-refresh) for this. its easy to use

1) Copy the whole MNMBottomPullToRefresh folder into your project

2) In your UIViewController class, create a MNMBottomPullToRefreshManager to link an UITableView and the MNMPullToRefreshView. Use a sentence like this in viewDidLoad:

```
pullToRefreshManager_ = [[MNMBottomPullToRefreshManager alloc] initWithPullToRefreshViewHeight:60.0f tableView:table withClient:self];


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
[pullToRefreshManager_ tableViewScrolled];
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate: (BOOL)decelerate
 {
  [pullToRefreshManager_ tableViewReleased];
 }


- (void)bottomPullToRefreshTriggered:(MNMBottomPullToRefreshManager *)manager
  {
   //method to get more data 
  // [self CallWebServiceToLoadMorePAYMENTS];

  }
}
```

After reloading tableview call

```
[pullToRefreshManager_ tableViewReloadFinished];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just rolled my own "pull up to refresh" Cocoapod:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/LottiesBottom
It's based off Lottie by airbnb. You can plugin which ever Lottie animation you want.