# How to create RefreshControl at the bottom of TableView Swift 2+

Tags: ios, swift2

Please help me if you have any idea how to implement `UIRefreshControl` at the bottom of `UITableView`?

[Like this](https://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/), but just under the table view when you drag it up.

When I'll drag table view I want similar result as `RefreshControl`. While I drag it to top "loading circle" is filled, and if I don't drag to the end, and "loading circle" is not filled entirely, my refresh func isn't called

Need help with implementation just for Swift!

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30437448/3543861

Comment: Thank you very much! But this is not exactly that I'm looking for. When I'll drag TableView I want similar result as RefareshControl. During I drag it to top "loading circle" is fill. And if I don't drag to the end, and "loading circle" will not is fill entire, my refresh func isn't to call

Comment: you can accomplish that in the scrollViewDidScroll method from that link.. Write the code yourself

Answer (score 1):

Check this on [Github](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl)

You just have to set

> triggerVerticalOffset

Comment: Thanks, but I have the condition: use just Swift. Do you know the similar library for Swift2+?

Comment: But I think use can use this pod and implement in swift using Bridging.

Comment: Okey. I never do this before, but I try! Thank you!